# How do I make the flip animation on a modal view on the iPad transparent in the background?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

How do I make my flip animation transparent so the view behind it is shown through?

Here's some of my code:

```
EditInfoViewController *editController = [[EditInfoViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditInfoViewController" bundle:nil];
editController.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *editNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:editController];

editNavController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
editNavController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self.navigationController presentModalViewController:editNavController animated:YES];
```

A picture is worth 1000 words (this was taken during the flip animation):

[image]

Comment: I bet you'll have to animate it yourself, instead of relying on modal transitions.

Comment: One other thought: Depending on how the view animation works, in re: prefab transitions, maybe try setting the background to clearColor.  I say that knowing you've probably already tried it.  :)

Comment: AMayes is right. As far as I know, there is no way to make the background of a `UIVIewController`, or any subclass thereof without making the whole thing transparent with the `alpha` property. You'll have to do a custom animation with a `UIView`