# iOS 8 - Unable to make the UIModalPresentationFormSheet transparent

Tags: ios, presentviewcontroller, uimodalpresentationstyle

In iOS 7, I have a piece of code that works similar to requirements mentioned in

1. [How do I make the flip animation on a modal view on the iPad transparent in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17180508/how-do-i-make-the-flip-animation-on-a-modal-view-on-the-ipad-transparent-in-the?rq=1)

and

2. [Seamlessly flip from one modal view to another, without showing a solid colour background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017413/seamlessly-flip-from-one-modal-view-to-another-without-showing-a-solid-colour-b?rq=1)

and the way I implemented it in iOS 7 is by using the methods mentioned in this question
 [UIModalPresentationFormSheet can't change superview background to clear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885462/uimodalpresentationformsheet-cant-change-superview-background-to-clear?rq=1)

so far working well until Apple released iOS 8. In iOS 8 modController.view.superView is returning nil, which greatly affects my animation by showing a gray background. It'll be a great help if anyone has a idea on how to fix this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it for now by creating a custom UIView.

Comment: I am also facing same issue, can you please provide some help?